# Use StatusBar for Mouse Hover on Button

Tags: python, wxpython, statusbar

In my code, I've created StatusBar `self.CreateStatusBar()`. I can use this statusbar in `MenuItem`. Like Below:

[image]

How can I use this statusbar in Button. Like, when I will enter my mouse over button, I will use this statusBar to give information about that button.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
import wx

class MyFrame(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kw):
        super(MyFrame, self).__init__(*args, **kw) 
        self.Init()

    def Init(self):   

        panel = wx.Panel(self)
        button = wx.Button(panel, label='Button', pos=(30, 25))     
        button.Bind(wx.EVT_ENTER_WINDOW, self.OnMouseEnter)
        button.Bind(wx.EVT_LEAVE_WINDOW, self.OnMouseLeave)
        self.StatusBar = self.CreateStatusBar()
        self.SetSize((200, 170))
        self.SetTitle('Statusbar...')
        self.Centre()
        self.Show(True)     

    def OnMouseEnter(self, e):  
        self.StatusBar.SetStatusText("Mouse Enter Event...")
        e.Skip()               

    def OnMouseLeave(self, e):
        self.StatusBar.SetStatusText("Mouse Leave Event...")
        e.Skip()   

def Main():

    app = wx.App()
    MyFrame(None)
    app.MainLoop()    

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Main()
```